# Sorting an object with null properties yields different results between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, firefox

I have an object array that I am trying to apply 2 sorts to. A simple alphabetical sort to a 'name' property and then a sort on a 'rank' property that can either be numeric or null. Objects with a null 'rank' should sort to the end of the final array.

This code is working as intended in Chrome, Safari, and Edge. In Firefox however, it is reversing the alphabetical order of all objects with a null 'rank'.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lfu1z39/

Code:

```
const data = [
    {
    "name": "F",
    "rank": 2
    },{
    "name": "B",
    "rank": null
    },{
    "name": "A",
    "rank": 1
    },{
    "name": "E",
    "rank": null
    },{
    "name": "D",
    "rank": null
    },{
    "name": "C",
    "rank": 2
    }
]

const nameSort = (a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();

    if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
    } else if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};

const rankSort = (a, b) => {
    if (a.rank === null) {
        return 1;
    } else if (b.rank === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

console.log('name only', data.sort(nameSort));
console.log('name and rank', data.sort(nameSort).sort(rankSort));
```

Which browser is correct here? Or, can anything be done to bring consistency between browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you return the wrong value for same values for comparing.

For example with `a.rank === null` **and** b.rank === null, you return `1` but the correct value is in this case zero to return.

The implementation of a sorting algorithm is up to the vendor and can return differetn results, depending on for example order of sorting, like from start or from end.

*To overcome this problem, you need to implement an algorithm which returns zero for equal values.*

```js
const data = [{ name: "F", rank: 2 }, { name: "B", rank: null }, { name: "A", rank: 1 }, { name: "E", rank: null }, { name: "D", rank: null }, { name: "C", rank: 2 }]

const nameSort = (a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();

    return nameA > nameB || -(nameA < nameB);
};

const rankSort = (a, b) => (a.rank === null) - (b.rank === null) 
        
    

console.log('name only', data.sort(nameSort));
console.log('name and rank', data.sort(nameSort).sort(rankSort));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to solve this problem. You could use combination of `Array.prototype.sort()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` method to get the final result. First, apply alphabetical sort to the name property. After that use array filter method to put all the null 'rank' property at the end of the array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'F',
    rank: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    rank: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'A',
    rank: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'E',
    rank: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'D',
    rank: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'C',
    rank: 2,
  },
];

data.sort((x, y) => x.name.localeCompare(y.name));
console.log('name only', data);

const ret = [
  ...data.filter((x) => x.rank !== null),
  ...data.filter((x) => x.rank === null),
];
console.log('name and rank', ret);
```